# What am I doing wrong with my routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to use a custom route to go to `/admin/home` but it keeps giving me the error: `undefined local variable or method 'home_admins_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8272855808>:0x007f8272b9f298>` when using `= link_to 'Home', home_admins_path`

When I run `rake routes` it appears that path is valid:
`home_admins_path GET    /admins/home(.:format)                                                     admins#home`

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins

  get '/admins/home' => 'admins#home', as: :home_admins_path

  resources :admins

  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

**admins_controller.rb**

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def home
    render "admins/home.html.haml"
  end
end
```

Comment: I hope this answer would also be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053754/ruby-on-rails-routes/7054021#7054021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a named path using the `as` option, "_path" is appended by Rails to the name.  So for your route:

```
get '/admins/home' => 'admins#home', as: :home_admins_path
```

then named route becomes `home_admins_path_path`.

So, to get `home_admins_path` named route you need to change it to:

```
get '/admins/home' => 'admins#home', as: :home_admins
```

Another option would be to add this route as a `collection` within the `resources :admin` like follows:

```
resources :admins do 
  collection do 
    get '/home', action: :home, as: :home
  end
end
```

And this will also give you a named route `home_admins_path`.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Still kind of new to this so I mess up the basics. Works like a charm now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify home_admins_path in "as". _path is automatically added by rails, so for your problem you just have to write the route like this

```
get '/admins/home' => 'admins#home', as: :home_admins
```

It will be expanded as home_admins_path or home_admins_url by rails.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality due to it's length. Though I agree, unfortunately answers like this are permitted. However, aside from their permitted nature, I urge you to expand upon this and provide a detailed answer instead of just a one-liner.